# How to find duplicate items in list<>?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "b", "r", "t" };
```

How can I get only "a","b"?

I tried to do like this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "b", "r", "t" };
List<string> test_list = new List<string>(); 

test_list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

Now test_list has {"a", "b", "r", "t"}
And then:

```
test_list = test_list.Except(list).ToList();
```

So that was my fail point, cause Except() deleted all elements.

*Could you help me with solution?*

Comment: Take a look at the `GroupBy` method.

Comment: Totally expected behavior. Except() excepted from test_list all entries found in list. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's a final bachelor work =) 
I'm doing a system with word search from data base by chosen filter

Comment: Alex, since [the @Sachin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15866810/200449) is the best, as you noted in comment to it, you should accept it as answer by clicking on the left of that answer the shallow check mark helping others to understand that the question was answered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
var duplicates = list.GroupBy(a => a).SelectMany(ab => ab.Skip(1).Take(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't understand why this answer is upvoted. Any one tried it with `{ "a", "a",  "b", "b", "a", "r", "t" }` ?

Comment: You _could_ do that. Honestly, I had to think too long and hard about _why_ this method actually works. I much prefer l4V's; much more readable and to-the-point. EDIT: Maybe it's faster, but I doubt performance is any issue at all in this case.

Comment: I4V, you're right, it does not work correctly

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Well I think the point is that this *doesn't* work. If you put in `{ "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "r", "t" }` you get out `"a" "a" "b"`

Comment: @MatthewWatson I was commenting to another poster (forgot the name) who suggested a correction that worked (see MarcinJuraszek's answer) but they subsequently deleted their comment.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Ah, ok. That makes more sense. :)

Comment: ((It's fixed with the latest edit))

Comment: Sorry guy's, I accepted my mistake. I just test with above given problem. But now I have updated my answer

Comment: .GroupBy(a => a).SelectMany(ab => ab.Skip(1))
:D I just found that this one was the best solution for me

Comment: @Alex, if it is eventually the best solution to you, you should accept it as answer by clicking on the left of answer a shallow check mark

Answer (score 16):

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "b", "r", "t" };

var dups = list.GroupBy(x => x)
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 10):

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "a", "b", "b", "r", "t" };

var distinct = new HashSet<string>();    
var duplicates = new HashSet<string>();

foreach (var s in list)
    if (!distinct.Add(s))
        duplicates.Add(s);

// distinct == { "a", "b", "r", "t" }
// duplicates == { "a", "b" }
```

Comment: +1 probably the most efficient approach.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This is very good if you always want all the duplicate entries.. I have provided a bit more efficient (and lazy as well) solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72647392/661933

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is using `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
var dups = list.GroupBy(s => s)
               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
               .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var duplicates = list.GroupBy(s => s).SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1).Take(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is incorrect 1st version of [@Sachin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15866810/200449), see comments to it and its edits

Comment: That was the best option for me. I miss one point in my question: if I have {a,a,a,b,b,r}, so at the output I should get {a,a,b}

Answer (score 0):

```
var duplicates = list.GroupBy(a => a).SelectMany(ab => ab.Skip(1).Take(1)).ToList();
```

It will be more efficient then the one using `Where(g => g.Count() > 1)` and will return only one element from every group.